# New Google Analytics property not capturing traffic

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-sdk

Hell,
We have a production prperty for google analytics and out IOS and Android Apps are recording the events and data.

I am trying to create a test property in order to use it in the test environment, how ever that does not seem to work. here is what I have done:
1. Created a new prperty under the production account
2. Created Streams for Ios, Android and Web
3. Cannot find the Tracking Id for the new property. Sme places I have read it is in the format 
UA-AccountId-PrpertySlnumnber. I have tried that but not result.
4. Some places suggested to use the measurementid (G-xxxxxxxx) available in the web Stream and I used that but still it wont work.

However if I use PROD tracking Id in the code, it perfectly works. Am I missing anything? Any guidance will really help.

Comment: Is it an APP+WEB profile or APP only? Have you reconnect your new property to your Firebase Console?

Comment: Initially I didnot reconnect. However I created a test app, test account and test properties and tested (referred to a blog post) and I could see the live data and events etc...

Answer (score 0):

(Added as answer because low reputation doesn't allow comment)

Can you clarify if this is what is occurring?

- Production property with production tracking ID shows data
- Test property with test measurementID does not show data
- Test property with test tracking ID (tracking ID not found)

Or did you mean Test property with Production tracking ID shows data?

Based on this, it sounds like your properties are not replicates. Are they both the same type of property? I would suggest going through the instructions on Google with both properties side-by-side.

See further info below:

https://www.blog.google/products/marketingplatform/analytics/new-way-unify-app-and-website-measurement-google-analytics/

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7372977

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9304153

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9303323

Answer (score 0):

A couple things to consider.

- Have you setup the firebase console correctly?
- Are the data being sent out correctly? You can check this in your network calls.
- Is there a lot of data being tracked already in your current environment (Staging or dev)? Google analytics perform sampling on the data when there's too much data coming in. I think it's 1 million data points per day. It does 1% sampling on our production app.

Answer (score 0):

I think my mistake was I was trying to create a new google analytics for firebase property but was not connecting it to the firebase.

The reason behind is I was trying to accomodate it with the older Google Analytics SDK implementation and I was not finding any documentation which said no  it is mot possible.

Now, I created properties connected them through google firebase projects and enabled analytics with them. In my xamarin app I used Xamarin.Firebase packaged to get it working.